# Coverging sequences and monotonicity

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a real convergent sequence to a number $l$. We can prove that $(\left| x_n - l\right|)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is ultimately monotone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we cannot. For example, let $x_n=1/n$ if $n$ is odd, and $2/n$ if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

No, the sequence
$$
\frac13, \frac12, \frac15, \frac14, \frac17, \frac16, \ldots
$$
converges to $0$ but is never monotonic.